# NuxtJs Customizing first loading page on generated static output

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a generated (static) nuxtjs page. I could not customize the first page which shows the loading state. Here is the screenshot. It's also what you see when you use the 'spa' mode instead of 'universal'.

[image]

I am not talking about the loading which can be customized using the loading property inside nuxt.config.js. Although I have created a custom component for the loading state as explained [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/) (which works correctly), this one is entirely different from it.

For a hosted example checkout https://daamat.web.app. It is especially visible on a slower connection.

Comment: I don't see any loading over the site you've provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NuxtJS intention of generating static pages is to avoid such loading indications, during the generation of pages (plural - pages) all API calls that page is making are done at the server (or local machine) data is rendered to page, and saved in the generated HTML file.

When you generating a site by `nuxt generate` you should use 'universal' instead of 'spa'.

Comment: Generating a `universal` mode app seems to have solved the problem. Thanks.